# 2d Vector Insertions in C++

Tags: c++, vector

Currently working on a graph representation using a vector of vectors.  I am attempting to insert a vector of edges at a specific location within `adjacencies`.  `adjacencies` is defined as `adjacencies = new std::vector< std::vector<Edge*>* >;`

I am running into an issue with the vector not inserting at the specific `.stateId` location.  It is quite possible the logic isn't what I intend it to be.  Do i need to be resizing the vector?  From documentation, I would assume the vector will resize automatically when inserting at a location not currently in the vector.  I appreciate the clarification.

Here is my method:

```
/*
 * Connecting Edge vertF -----> vertT via weigh
 * adjacencies[v][e]
 */
void GraphTable::InsertEdgeByWeight(Vertex* vertF,Vertex* vertT, char weigh){
        Edge* tempEdge = new Edge(vertT,weigh);
        /*
         * Need to figure out how to properly allocate the space in adjacencies.size()
         * Test 4 works with initial ID 0 but not test 5 with ID 4
         */
         std::vector<Edge*>* temp_vec = new vector<Edge*>;
         temp_vec->push_back(tempEdge);
            /*if vector at location doesnt exist, we will push a new vector of edges otherwise we
             * will need to push the edge into the current vector
             */
         if(adjacencies->size()<vertF->thisState.stateId){
             adjacencies->resize(vertF->thisState.stateId);
             adjacencies[vertF->thisState.stateId].push_back(temp_vec);
         }else{
            adjacencies[vertF->thisState.stateId].push_back(temp_vec);
         }
        cout<< adjacencies->capacity() << endl;
        //cout<< adjacencies->max_size() << endl;

}
```

Comment: You are always inserting `temp_vec` into your data structure, where `temp_vec` is a vector itself! Where is the else case wherein the vector at that location already exists, and you need to only insert the new edge into the existing vector?

Comment: There is really no reason to use `std::vector<std::vector<T>*>` instead of `std::vector<std::vector<T> >`. The same might apply for the inner `Edge*`, though I can't say for sure without knowing how it is defined. You'll have to manually `delete` everything you created with `new`. If you can use C++11 features, you should probably not use `new` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are resizing `adjacencies` to a value of `vertF->thisState.stateId` and then calling `adjacencies[vertF->thisState.stateId]`.
If the size of a vector/array is "x", then the highest index is "x-1".

So you should write this instead -:

`adjacencies[vertF->thisState.stateId-1].push_back(temp_vec);`

Edit : As Ankit Garg pointed out in the comments, you should probably push `tempEdge` directly to `adjacencies` instead of creating a temporary vector.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding from my comment, I think you must do something like this:

```
if(adjacencies->size() < vertF->thisState.stateId)
{
    // the vector does not exist, hence push_back the new vector
    .....
}
else
{
    // vector already exists, so just push_back the edge
    adjacencies[vertF->thisState.stateId].push_back(temp_edge);
}
```